# test program where user enters questions and answers continues to give 0 for correct percentage

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong calculating the percent of correct answers. The program is supposed to take input from the user on how many questions, what the questions are, and the answers. I have the questions and answers in a separate list but each question and answer in the same index go together. I pretty much figured out everything up to the grade_test function when trying to find the percent of correct answers. any help or pointers would be appreciated.

```
def main():
    numQ = int(input("How many questions are on the test?"))
    valid_choices = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
    questions = [input(f'What is question {num}?')for num in range(1,numQ+1)]
    answer_key = [a for a in (input(f'Anwser to question {num} is?')for num in range(1,numQ+1)) if a in valid_choices]
    answers = [a for a in (input(f'What is the anwser to question{num}? ') for num in range(1, numQ+1)) if a in valid_choices]

    result = grade_test(answers, answer_key)
    print(result)

def grade_test(answers, answer_key):
    correct = 0
    incorrect = 0
    for i in range(len(answers)):
        if answers[i] == answer_key[i]:
            correct = correct+1
        else:
            incorrect += incorrect
    percent_correct = (correct % len(answer_key) * 100)
    return percent_correct

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1):

There are more problems then finding the percentage of correct answers.

- questions, answer_key and answers are three separate lists which can have different size because of your if-statement, for example:

  ```
    numQ = 5
    # input 1,2,3,4,5, size equal to numQ
    questions = [1,2,3,4,5]
    # input 1,2,a,b,c, size equal to valid choice
    answer_key = [a,b,c]
    # input a,b,1,2,3, size also equal to valid choice
    answers = [a,b]
  ```

  as you can see, they have different size so you may have IndexError, also items in answer_key and answer are related to different questions
- `incorrect += incorrect` just do 0 + 0 = 0, though it has no effect as you don't use it in calculation of percentage

For the percentage problems, you need to know the difference between `/` and `%` operator:

- `/` is use for division, e.g. 5 / 11 = 0.45454... and 11 / 5 = 2.2
- `%` is use for remainder of division, e.g. 5 % 11 = 5 and 11 % 5 = 1

Answer (score 0):

its the wrong operator!

```
percent_correct = (correct % len(answer_key) * 100)
```

should be

```
`percent_correct = (correct / len(answer_key) * 100)
```